# Angular library secondary entrypoint test code coverage problem

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular9, angular-library, karma-coverage

I am using angular library with secondary entrypoint
My library folder structure is

- my-library

  - secondary-entrpoint 1

    - service 1
  - secondary-entrypoint 2

    - service 2
  - src

And I used this command `ng test my-library --code-coverage`

The secondary entry points' service test doesn't execute.

Then I tried, changing "test.ts" context path('./') with '../' which is under the src folder.
Tests were executed but code coverage doesn't create.

How can I execute tests for a secondary entry point?

Answer (score 10):

That is because the source root of your project is pointing to `projects/your-library/src` and when running tests it does not take into account the other entry points.

To fix this just change the sourceRoot property in your "angular.json" file to `projects/your-library`, everything else should still work fine.

Comment: I have multiple secondary entrpoints. So I can't set sourceroot property on angular.json

Comment: All your secondary entry points have the same root, so following your example in your angular.json you should set `"sourceRoot": "projects/my-library"` instead of `"sourceRoot": "projects/my-library/src"` that is what Angular sets as default

Comment: I got Mert's answer to work by also moving the test.ts file to the "project/my-library" level AND changing my tsconfig.spec.ts files from "src/test.ts" to "test.ts"

Comment: It worked great for me. tnx man :)

Comment: After moving test.ts 1 level up, no need to change `sourceRoot` in angular.json, changing test/options/main path is enough.

Comment: Actually, despite tests run, they don't reflect in the code coverage report. With or without changes to `sourceRoot`, only primary endpoint shows up in coverage. Any way to fix it?